# S Corp Taxes under GOP Bill

Tags: united-states, taxes

[Hacking the Tax Plan: Ways to
Profit Off the Republican Tax Bill](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2017/12/12/upshot/tax-hacks.html?_r=0) notes:

> If you run a pass-through business that earns up to $157,500 a year if you’re single ($315,000 if you’re married), you get a 21 percent tax break on all profit that comes through your company — in other words, only 80 percent of that income would be taxed.

Let's say an S Corp owned by 1 person with no employees makes $200,000 a year through consulting, i.e. billing his time.

Does that mean that only 80% of $200,000, i.e. $160,000 would be eligible for taxes?

Answer (score 1):

The limit has nothing to do with the income of the business entity; it has entirely to do with your (total) taxable income, both from the business and otherwise.

From the [conference report](https://files.taxfoundation.org/20171215175456/TCJA_Conference_Report.pdf) (I will replace this with the actual law once that is published):

> (3) MODIFICATIONS TO LIMIT BASED ON TAXABLE INCOME.—
>
> > (A) EXCEPTION FROM LIMIT.—In the case of any taxpayer whose
> >     taxable income for the taxable year does not exceed the threshold amount, 
> >     paragraph (2) shall be applied without regard to subparagraph (B)

This is from Part II, Sec. 11011.

The subparagraph (B) limit is referring to the limitation that you cannot take a deduction greater than 50% of your W2 wages.

Further down, is a very similarly worded exception to the exclusion of Personal Services businesses:

> (3) EXCEPTION FOR SPECIFIED SERVICE BUSINESSES BASED ON TAXPAYER’S INCOME.—

In both cases, the exclusion is based on the taxpayer's taxable income.

If your income was a bit more than that, and you didn't have any (legitimate) way to avoid some of that money hitting your personal tax return (or didn't want to), you'd have a $50,000 phaseout period ($100,000 filing jointly) where you'd still get to deduct some of the business income, but not all of it.